# Is there a way to have two mouse cursors on screen, controlled by different input devices (e.g. mouse, trackpad)?

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad

I am using an external monitor with my MacBook Pro. I switch between them quite often. Whenever I'm working on whatever's on my MacBook, I use my MacBook built-in keyboard/trackpad. When I interact with the monitor, I use an external keyboard and mouse.

I was wondering if there was a way to have *two* mouse cursors—one on each monitor, each controlled by either the trackpad or keyboard. This would stop me from having to drag the mouse across monitors every single time I wanted to switch between them.

I realize that some people may scoff me for asking this, as it is practically the same as having two Macs. However, I don't see how that's a bad thing. If I can emulate two computers with just one, I see that as a big win! I'm almost there with this external monitor setup.

Note: One possibility is to use BetterTouchTool to use a button to change to the other screen. It would work like this: press button → mouse position saved to slot 2 → mouse position moved to saved position 1. And if I press it again, it switches back to the same monitor: press button → mouse position saved to slot 1 → mouse position moved to saved position 1. I'm just looking for something more seamless (and also because I'm highly curious if it's even possible to have two mouses on-screen. I've never even seen that on Windows).

Comment: TBH/ I've never seen this implemented on _any_ os I've used over the past 40-odd years.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the need here.  I have a 27" iMac and a 22" screen next to it and to go from  one edge of one screen to the opposite edge of the other takes less than 3 inches of mouse movement.  This seems like an extremely over-bodged solution to something that you shouldn't have an issue with to begin with.  How is your mouse configured?  Is acceleration (tracking speed) turned down too low?

Comment: Honestly, it's not. It's fine unless I keep switching back and forth. Idk, maybe if it switched automatically it would feel more "seamless"

Comment: @Allan my MacBook and external monitor are 50cm apart from each other and pointing towards me; when looking one I can barely see the other, that's why I use the trackpad when working on the left and the external mouse when working on the right. Switching would be easier if you just had 2 cursors.